# Stop alloy analyser from within alloy IDE when the provided scop is large

Tags: alloy

How to stop alloy analyzer when because of a large scope in run command, it stops responding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very simple! my bad! You just need to push the Stop button in the toolbar!

since always the execution was so fast, I never noticed that in alloy IDE, Execute button turns into Stop button during a model execution!